# Combining Bootstrap col and row classes on single element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**one:**

```
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="row">
       . 
       .
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

**two:**

```
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12 row">
   .
   .
  </div>
 </div>
```

Is both the implementations are same?can i use the 2 method so that i can reduced the mark-up.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to [**Bootstrap's own API documentation**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid), when [**nesting columns**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting) any columns `.col` should be nested within a `.row`. The two should not be combined on a single element.

Aside from the fact this makes more sense semantically- the underlying CSS properties both classes affect are reliant on this structure.

Also note, when using `col-md-12` in isolation, you are effectively creating a full width element (which a row is anyway). In which case using the grid layout *may* not be relevant unless you have other elements showing/coming into play at different screen sizes.

**Right (if using other columns as well as `col-md-12`):**

```
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="row">
       . 
       .
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

**Wrong:**

```
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12 row">
   .
   .
  </div>
 </div>
```

If you just want a full width element, you dont need to use the grid layout and/or can remove one level of nesting.

Comment: Yes! The two classes set different CSS attributes. These attributes rely on `.col` being within `.row` in order to work as anticipated

Answer (score 0):

1.If you need multiple `.col-` in a row then you may write as following..

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        .
        .
        .
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        .
        .
        .
    </div>
</div>

2. if you need to divide  `.col-` in more `.col` then

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                .
                .
                .
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                .
                .
                .
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
     .
     .
    </div>
</div>
```